# Is $p_1p_2...p_k - 1$ ever a perfect power?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is $p_1p_2...p_k - 1$ ever a perfect power, where $p_1 < p_2 < ... < p_k$ are the smallest primes?

The case for squares is simple, but I am struggling to generalise to all powers.

Comment: $2-1=1^n$ for any $n$ - do you want to exclude this case? And you always get a first power, of course.

Comment: @MarkBennet yes, we can exclude that and regard it as the trivial case

Answer (score 3):

I think I have worked it out myself:

Let $p_1p_2...p_k = x^n + 1$. As pointed out by asdf, $n$ cannot be even. We can reduce our search to the case when $n$ is prime, since any power where $n$ is composite can be reduced to the power of a prime.

Since all the primes up to $p_k$ do not divide $x$, we have that $x > p_k$. This in turn gives us that $n < k$. But, since $k < p_k$, $n$ must be a prime contained in the product $p_1p_2...p_k$. Hence, let $n=P$, where $p_1 < P \le p_k$.

By Fermat's Little Theorem, $x^P \equiv x\mod P$. From the condition in the question, we also have that $x^P \equiv -1 \mod P$. Therefore, $P \mid x+1$.

Hence, let $x=tP-1$, where $t>0$. We therefore have that

$$p_1p_2...p_k = (tP-1)^P+1 = (tP)^P+...+\binom{P}{1}(tP)$$

However, since $P^2$ divides the RHS but not the LHS, we have a contradiction for $k>1$.

Comment: That looks good!

Answer (score 1):

If you exclude the case $2-1=1^2$ then the answer is NO.

Suppose you have $$p_1p_2...p_n=x^2+1$$

Then you would have $3|x^2+1$ and this is a contradiction.

You can similarly exclude all even powers.

As far as generalisation goes, I'll think about it a bit more and post if I make some progress.

Comment: Cubes don't work either.  They fail $\bmod 9$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: do you mean $5$ rather than $9$? ($9$ doesn't divide the LHS.)

Comment: Meaning $9$.  A cube would have to be $\equiv -1\bmod 3$ which, for cubes, then forces $\equiv -1\bmod 9$.  But the quantity from which $1$ is subtracted is only a multiple of $3$ not a multiple of $9$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: thanks for the explanation. Working mod 5 also excludes cubes.

Comment: @asdf have a look at my solution and see if it works

Comment: The OP already mentions that the case for squares is simple, so this is not really providing a substantial part of an answer.